# is there a difference between request.user and actual User object?

Tags: django, django-users

I have defined my UserDetail model, which has one to one relation with User.

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ....
```

but when I am trying to access UserDetail object through request.user in my view it is throwing me error as "*User has no userdetail.*".

```
form = UpdateProfile(request.user.userdetail)
```

while I am able to use *user.userdetail* in Django shell.
I have no idea why it is happening, is request.user have some differences with User object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is because that particular user does not have an associated UserDetail instance.

Comment: or there is not logged in user, so you are actually looking at `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser`

Comment: Thanks a lot @daniel , I was thinking that current user have UserDetail instance for him but unfortunately I was logged in as super user which doesn't.

Comment: thanks @burhan for editing my question and pointing out another scenario.